# Postgresql JSON has key

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I'm trying to understand the way the `Postgresql` is dealing with `JSON`. I've declared a two-columns table and I'd like to create a new View to get some boolean values.

So far, I've been able to get the value as text but what I'd like to get is whether the field is defined or not.
For example, if the `JSON` has the key `frameMenuData.frameElement`, it should print `has_frame` to true.

```
SELECT
  customer_data->>'frameMenuData'->>'frameElement' AS has_frame,
FROM
  simple_list
WHERE
  TRUE
  AND guid='AAAA';
```

The above code gives me the content of that row. I need to know if `customer_data->>'frameMenuData'->>'frameElement'` is defined or not.

How could I achieve that ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Problem solved. It was barely easy.

```
SELECT (customer_data->>'frameMenuData'->>'frameElement' IS NULL) AS has_frame,
```

Comment: I think you just want `customer_data->>'frameMenuData' ? 'frameElement' AS has_frame` see: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html and search for